# Resizing text in illustrator, 5 to 6 point (some characters hidden?)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have selected text and increased its size, eg, 5 to 6 point. Then part of text is missing.

The picture shows Porcupine. The letter 'e' is hidden after the size increase. I do not know how to fix it? Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like **Type on a Path**.

Your **path is too short**. Use the **Direct Selection Tool** (white arrow) to extend the length of the path to allow more text to show.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, really sorry but new to illustrator. How do i do that? I tried selecting with Direct selection tool but it just moved all the text.. There is a small + symbol in a box.

Comment: The red [+] indicates there is more text which is not visible.

Comment: Thanks. I tried again with Direct selection tool on the path anchor and it did not work. It just dragged the word around.

Comment: You aren't clicking in the right spot. You have to click the **end point** of the **path**. Watch the animation above.

Comment: Hi Scott,Thank you for your previous answer. I have been trying this on some text that is on a curved path but cannot seem to get the end points to stretch it out. Is there a different way of doing this? Thanks in advance!